# Editing Sysprep Unattend.xml after Sysprep

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sysprep

I have an image of a Server 2008 R2 system which has been Sysprepped and was shutdown prior to its first boot. Now, it would seem I screwed the XML file up as it fails halfway through the Serialize section when booted. (To be clear, it fails on the boot *after* taking the image)

What I'm wondering is, can I alter the Unattend.xml file at this stage using my ability to directly manipulate the saved image?

If so, do I edit the original (In the sysprep directory) or is it transferred elsewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `unattend.xml` file may be in either of:

- `C:\Windows\Panther\`
- `C:\Windows\Panther\unattend\`

inside the image.

Comment: Thanks Chris - it's directly in C:\Windows\Pather on mine. I will try editing this and see if I can affect the result of the bootup

Comment: Worked a treat - yes, you can edit the unattend.xml file in this location after running Sysprep!

Answer (score 1):

1. Mount the sysprep'd image as a VHD on a VM or if it's captured as a WIM them mount the WIM to a newly created empty directory
2. Navigate to `C:\Windows\Panther` and update the XML file in-place
3. Dismount the WIM file and save allowing it to be used again or else edit the XML file on the VHD directly allowing over-write

This would resolve your issue.